# Keyword not supported using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a mvc web project.When I run it, I took that error."Keyword not supported: compatible Parameter name: keyword". I looked at web.config and appconfig. But I could not see any error.what can I do for this error?

**my web config connection string**

```
add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.Model.csdl|res://*/DataModel.Model.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.Model.msl;provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;port=5432;timeout=15;pooling=True;minpoolsize=1;maxpoolsize=500;commandtimeout=30;compatible=2.2.3.0;host=localhost;database=toki;user id=postgres;password=master;sslmode=Disable;connectionlifetime=100;enlist=True;preloadreader=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

**my app config connection string**

```
add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.Model.csdl|res://*/DataModel.Model.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.Model.msl;provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;port=5432;timeout=15;pooling=True;minpoolsize=1;maxpoolsize=500;commandtimeout=30;compatible=2.2.3.0;host=localhost;database=toki;user id=postgres;password=master;sslmode=Disable;connectionlifetime=100;enlist=True;preloadreader=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `compatible=2.2.3.0;` from both connectionstrings.